# Find the general solution of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble finding the general solution of $$y''+ 4y = 8\tan(t)$$
I found the complementary solution which is $y= A\cos(2t)+ B\sin(2t)$. I also found that the particular solution is
$$
-2\ln \left|\tan(2t)+\sec(2t)\right| \cos(2t)+ 2\sin(2t)\cos(2t)- 2\cos(2t)\sin(2t)
$$
I know you obtain the answer by adding them together but my answer is wrong. I think I screwed up the particular solution.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you find the particular solution, and did you verify whether it indeed satisfies the given ODE?

Comment: One way to solve it would be to use the substitution: $\frac{dy}{dt}=w$. The equation becomes linear in w. I checked the solution using this method on Wolfram Alpha seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

So in this problem we can use the Method of variation of arbitrary constants 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
C'_1cos(2t)+C'_2sin(2t)=0  
\\
-2C'_1sin(2t)+2C'_2cos(2t)=8tan(t)
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
This system of equations we solve with respect to variables $$ C'_1 , C'_2 $$
We have to have 
$$ 
  \begin {pmatrix}
   cos(2t)& sin(2t)\\
   -sin(2t)& cos(2t)\\
\end {pmatrix}
$$
(I divided the last equality by 2)

then the determinant of this matrix will be 1 $$ \Rightarrow$$
$$
 C'_1(t)=\int-8sin(t))^2dt = -8\int\frac{(1-cos(2t))dt}{2}=-4(t-\frac{sin(2t)}{2})+C_1
$$
Finally we need to find $ C_2$  $$ \Rightarrow$$
$$
C'_2(t)=4\int\frac{((cos(t))^2-(sin(t))^2)sin(t)dt}{cos(t)}=4\int\frac{(1-(tan(t))^2)tan(t)dt}{(tan(t))^2+1}+C_2
$$
replace the variable $$ tan(t)=m $$
$\Rightarrow $
$dt=\frac{dm}{m^2+1} $ 
$$
4\int\frac{(1-m^2)mdm}{(m^2+1)^2}=2\int\frac{(1-m^2)d(m^2)}{(m^2+1)^2} 
$$
$z=m^2 $ $\Rightarrow $
$$
2\int\frac{(1-z)dz}{(z+1)^2}=-2\int\frac{d(z+1)}{z+1}+4\int\frac{d(z+1)}{(z+1)^2}=-2log(z+1)-\frac{4}{z+1}+C_2
$$

Finally we found the desired functions and it remains only to substitute them in the original(your equation) equation  (1) :)
Just do not forget to make a reverse replacement